# When attempting to integrate Firebase with my Flutter app, I encountered an error. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue effectively?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to connect with firebase but there is an error occured while connecting Please Help

I try lots of cmd properties like flutter clean, flutter pub get, flutter upgrade. but it couldn't work
and also i didn't know about gradle, sdk . I think the problem is rise because of this also

Comment: What is the error?? Without more details (code and error) it will be nearly impossible to someone to help you.